# LogIn with MySQL and Session ID

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

The last days i read a lot about generating a LogIn with MySQL and Sessions. I would like to know if in case of security my approach is the right one.

- starting new Session with `session_start()`
- LogIn Form with eMail and password
- escaping eMail and password with `mysqli_real_escape_string` because of SQL injections
- checking if eMail and password exists in DB. Verify the password with `password_verify()` (password saved before in DB with `password_hash`)
- if exist `$SESSION['login'] = 1;` and link to main page

So far i understand the logic. Are there any objections to security ?

Here comes my problem. Now i would like to check on every site if the user is valid. As i understand it correct `session_start()` creates a SESSION-ID and a COOKIE called "PHPSESSID". To check if the user is valid i would do:

```
    session_start();
    $session_id = session_id();
    if ($_SESSION['login'] == 1 && $_SESSION[$session_id] == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) {
       echo "YES";
    } else {
       echo "NO";
    }
```

Is this correct and makes sense or i'm thinking in a wrong way and need to edit my logic.

Thank you for any help and advise.
Oliver

Comment: i would say checking for $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] is redundant as cookie is client-side and can be easily manipulated. Not great for security clearing or checking.

Comment: "escaping eMail and password with mysqli_real_escape_string because of SQL injections" no use  Prepared statements and bound paramaters

Comment: this should be asked on code revirew

Comment: What is the better way to check on every site if the user is valid? The site shouldn't work if the client copies the url and try to execute it from another computer. In the best way the session should work just where the client logged in.

Comment: @rtfm I don't think it's really appropriate for CR.

Comment: @OliverNatschke If they copy the URL they won't have the session cookie.

Comment: And if they copy all the cookies from the other computer, the `$_SESSION[$session_id] == $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` check will succeed, so that doesn't help.

Comment: ok .. so what is the usual solution? How can i proof validation with the generated Session ID ?

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['login'] == 1){//yipee}` unless your running a bank.

Comment: :-) no, not a bank but connection should be secure as the company saves sensible data. Is it really enough if i just check the login status ?

Comment: For what i need the Session ID? It's generated automatically but do i really need the SID to check user validation ?